# Simple For Loop taking ages

Tags: vba, excel

I have this simple loop designed to look at a block of data in excel:
it firstly identifies how many rows it extends down - this defines the number of iterations
then on each row N,  looks to see if the cell(N,B) is empty - if so deletes that row.

This seems to not work, also it takes ages! I need something that does this very quickly.

Any thoughts would be aprreciated

```
Sub PREBILLvariant2()

        Dim N As Long

 For N = 1 To Worksheets("EMEA input").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

If InStr(Cells(N, "B").Value, "") > 0 Then Worksheets("EMEA input").Cells(N, "B").EntireRow.Delete


    Next N

    End Sub
```

Comment: try turning off screen updating while you are in the loop.

Comment: You should count down from the last row to the first, otherwise once you've removed one row the other ones move up to fill the space and your iteration will go past the end of where you intended it to.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another method. I always found Filtering to be the fastest way to do these things.

```
Public Sub filterThenDelete()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim r As Excel.Range
    Set r = Sheets("EMEA input").UsedRange

    r.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=""

    Dim deleteRange As Excel.Range
    Set deleteRange = r.Offset(1, 0).Resize(r.Rows.Count - 1, r.Columns.Count).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    deleteRange.EntireRow.Delete

    Sheets("EMEA input").AutoFilterMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Just an FYI, for the AutoFilter, `Field:=2` is saying "Apply the filter found in Criteria1 to column 2 in the range selected." Or simply "Filter column B for blank values."

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
Sub PREBILLvariant3()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRows As Long, N As Long
    Dim rngToDelete As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set ws = Worksheets("EMEA input")
    lRows = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For N = 1 To lRows
        If ws.Cells(N, "B").Value <> "" Then
            If rngToDelete Is Nothing Then
                Set rngToDelete = ws.Cells(N, "B")
            Else
                Set rngToDelete = Union(rngToDelete, ws.Cells(N, "B"))
            End If
        End If
    Next N
    rngToDelete.EntireRow.Delete
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set ws = Nothing
End Sub
```

This collects, as a `Range` all the cells in B that are not empty (<> "") and deletes the rows in one go after the loop.

Checking for not empty (<> "") or `Len() > 0` is better IMO than using `InStr()`, as you are not looking for specific text.

Answer (score -2):

This is a more standart approach:

It loops over every row with content in column A and delete every row that has an empty cell in column C

```
Sub subDeleteRows()
    Dim lngRow As Long: lngRow = 1

    subSpeedUp True

    Do Until IsEmpty(Sheets("EMEA input").Cells(lngRow, 1))
        If IsEmpty(Sheets("EMEA input").Cells(lngRow, 2)) Then
            Sheets("EMEA input").Cells(lngRow, 2).EntireRow.Delete
        Else
            lngRow = lngRow + 1
        End If
    Loop

    subSpeedUp False
End Sub

Sub subSpeedUp(startStop As Boolean)
    If startStop Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
    Else
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

If you got the time, you should read this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff726673.aspx

Comment: This won't work. You need to loop backwards or some empty rows may be skipped.

Comment: @DougGlancy The ”skipping of empty rows” bug has been solved.

Comment: Generally: EntireRow.Delete, UsedRange, SpecialCells, AutoFilterMode and so forth should be avoided in VBA as it makes your code bug prone, makes your code less readable and gives you problem in larger programs.  One of the rules in data management is, to NEVER delete raw data. It is much better to leave your raw data on a separate sheet (or database or PowerPivot table), then quire that data and percent the result on your working sheet.